# How to create a `Union` based on a comma-separated string list

Tags: sql-server-2008, split, union

Suppose I am building a stored procedure in my SQL Server for table `my_table`.

The purpose of this stored procedure is to take an input keyword parameter `@keyword nvarchar(255)` and a comma-separated string '@vehicleList nvarchar(266)'.

`@catList` basically contains the values of of what filter checkboxes were checked on the front end (the options are car, truck, motorcycle). So, vehicle list might look list this:

```
@vehicleList = "car, truck, motorcycle"
```

or this

```
"car, motorcycle"
```

or this

```
"truck"
```

These checkbox names are the same as column names in `my_table`. I want to return certain columns from my_table based my on `@keyword` parameter being found in one of the columns, but ONLY if that column is in `@vehicleList`.

If the @vehicleList was always 'Car, Truck, Motorcyle', I could do this:

```
SELECT ID, T_Number, Car, Truck, Motorcycle, Date
FROM T_Ticket
WHERE Car Like '%' + @Keyword + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, T_Number, Car, Truck, Motorcycle, Date 
FROM T_Ticket
WHERE Truck Like '%' + @Keyword + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, T_Number, Car, Truck, Motorcycle, Date 
FROM T_Ticket
WHERE Motorcycle Like '%' + @Keyword + '%'
```

My question is, how would I do this based on a variable, comma-separated string that will be different every time the stored procedure is called?

Comment: You would build out dynamic SQL

Comment: How many possible columns are there? Perhaps your proc could simply return them all, and the app can exclude the columns that aren't needed/wanted. Can anyone else chime in on this idea? Am I wearing my "Bad Idea" jeans today?

Comment: @dave. The selected columns isn't dynamic. The filtering is. See the code in the pre edited version to understand the poorly explained requirement

Answer (score 2):

one way would be to `UNPIVOT` as below.

Unlike your `UNION ALL` this won't return duplicates in the event of multiple columns matching but I doubt you want that anyway (if you do use a `JOIN` instead of `EXISTS`).

```
SELECT *
FROM   T_Ticket
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   (VALUES ('Car', Car),
                              ('Truck', Truck),
                              ('Motorcycle', Motorcycle) ) V(colname, colvalue)
                      JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@vehicleList, ',') vl
                        ON ltrim(vl.value) = colname
               WHERE  colvalue LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%')
```

Comment: Arggh! I'm using 2008 and can't use `STRING_SPLIT`!!

Comment: Why did you include that function in your question then, @gwydion93 ? 2008 is very close to end of support so it's really important to tag your version when using such an old release. This means that answer's won't include functionality you don't have access to. I suggest have a search for an XML Splitter, for `delimitedSplit8k`.

Comment: My mistake. I removed that from the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Going down the dynamic SQL route, you could do:

```
DECLARE @vehicleList nvarchar(266);
DECLARE @keyword nvarchar(255);

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT ID, T_Number, Car, Truck, Motorcycle, Date' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13) +
           N'FROM T_Ticket' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13) +
           N'WHERE ' + 
           STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13) +
                         N'   OR ' + QUOTENAME([value]) + N' LIKE N''%'' + @Keyword + N''%'''
                  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@vehicleList,',')
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value(N'.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,8,N'') + N';';
--PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@keyword nvarchar(255)', @keyword = @keyword;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest way to achieve what you need

```
SELECT ID, T_Number, Car, Truck, Motorcycle, Date
FROM T_Ticket
WHERE (@vehicleList LIKE '%car%' AND Car LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%')
OR    (@vehicleList LIKE '%truck%' AND Truck LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%')
OR    (@vehicleList LIKE '%motorcycle%' AND Motorcycle LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%')
```